# What are these comands mean in buildkite?

Tags: node.js, yaml, pipeline, buildkite

What do these command mean in buildkit build pipeline?

- command:
- command: |
- command: >-

I am trying to build a build pipeline and I can't find any documentations on them. What are the differences between them?

example:

- command: |
    npm install
- command: npm install
- command: >- npm install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YAML has various ways to specify string properties:

```
single-quoted: "a single that can have : and other weird characters"
single-unquoted: another single command (but needs to avoid some special YAML characters, such as ":"
single-split: >
  a single
  line string
  command that's
  broken over
  multiple-lines
multi-line: |
  a
  multi-line
  string
```

Putting that into https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com you can see how it ends up:

```
{
  "single-quoted": "a single line command", 
  "single-unquoted": "another single command (but needs to avoid some special YAML characters, such as \":\"", 
  "single-split": "a single line string command that's broken over multiple-lines",
  "multi-line": "a\nmulti-line\ncommand\n"
}
```

You can find some related questions here about this too: [In YAML, how do I break a string over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines/21699210#21699210)

There's also some more examples here:
https://yaml-multiline.info

These are the three most common formats for Buildkite pipeline.yml commands are these:

```
command: "simple-command"
```

```
command: |
  npm install
  npm test
```

```
command:
  - "npm install"
  - "npm test"
```

(you can use `command` and `commands` interchangably)

For both of those last two examples, the commands in the list will be run in sequence, and fail as soon as any one of them fails. i.e. if the `npm install` command fails, the job will immediately finish with a failed state.